# css - do animation on image on a hover

Tags: html, css

My css code is:

```
.logo
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block !important;  
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.logo:hover
{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

And html is:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="img/logo200x200.png" class="logo" />
    Website
</a>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qz8g1c2r/)**

Can I make image rotate not only when my mouse is on image, but also when mouse is on text?

Comment: What text? Show the html. (On this site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `:hover` cover the whole `a` tag. In your example e.g. like this:

```
.navbar-brand:hover img {
    ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abvwh7aj/

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `.logo:hover` with `a:hover .logo`!

Here the working solution:

```css
.logo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block !important;  
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover .logo
{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200.png" class="logo" />Website
</a>
```